# Loops and functions working with variable prompts

Tags: javascript, function, loops, prompt

Have been struggling with getting this to work. I need to make sure my prompts reject numbers when asking for words, and rejects words when asking numbers. I need to use a loop to make sure that all prompts are answered or cancelled, and communicate if they cancelled at any point. Also i need to use a function to write the results to a table.

I've tried using `typeof` and `parseInt` but have not succeeded in getting it to reject numbers or words within an `if` statement. `typeof` always returns a string, even when i input a number or cancel.

I'm not sure how to use a `loop` in order to check that all prompts have been answered or cancelled, i thought about using `typeof` but since i couldn't get it to work earlier, i have not tried again.

Also, i thought `typeof` would work as far as telling the user if they cancelled at any point, but it always returns a string and not undefined.

When i tried having a bunch of `document.write` with the table info inside a `function` i couldn't get it to print anything. I've only succeeded using `.getElementById` and `.innerHTML` in order to write the variables to the table.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head> 
<title></title>  
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style>
table, th, td {border: 1px solid black; text-align:center; padding: 5px;}
</style>

<script>
var firstName=prompt("What is your first name?","");
var lastName=prompt ("What is your last name?","Doe");
var age=prompt ("What is your age?","21")
var phoneNumber=prompt ("What is your phone number?","123 456 7890")
var email=prompt ("What is your email?","username@domain.com")
</script>


</head>  
<body>

<table>
<tr>
<th>First Name</th>
<th>Last Name</th>
<th>Age</th>
<th>Phone</th>
<th>Email</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="tdFirstName"></td>
<td id="tdLastName"></td>
<td id="tdAge"></td>
<td id="tdPhoneNumber"></td>
<td id="tdEmail"></td>
</tr>
</table>

<script>
document.getElementById("tdFirstName").innerHTML = firstName;
document.getElementById("tdLastName").innerHTML = lastName;
document.getElementById("tdAge").innerHTML = age;
document.getElementById("tdPhoneNumber").innerHTML = phoneNumber;
document.getElementById("tdEmail").innerHTML =email;
</script>

</body>  
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var firstName;
do
{
    firstName=prompt("What is your first name?","");
}
while(!Number.isNaN(parseInt(firstName)));
```

and

```
var age;
do
{
    age=prompt("What is your age?","");
}
while(Number.isNaN(parseInt(age)));
```

or this:

```
var questions = [
    ["What is your name?", "string"],
    ["What is your age?", "number"]
];
for(var i = 0, j = questions.length; i < j; i++)
{
    var value, _break = false;
    for(;;)
    {
        value = prompt(questions[i][0]);
        if(value === null)
        {
            _break = true;
            break;
        }
        if(questions[i][1] == "number")
        {
            if(!Number.isNaN(parseInt(value)))
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        else if(questions[i][1] == "string")
        {
            if(Number.isNaN(parseInt(value)))
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if(_break)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Didn't work, when i type in numbers it still accepted them, and would not let the remaining prompts to launch